# Show running instance in single instance application

Tags: c#, .net, single-instance

I am building an application with C#.

I managed to turn this into a single instance application by checking if the same process is already running.

```
Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("SwapCardDesktop");
        if (pname.Length < 2)
        {
            // Launch Application
        }
```

I intend to have another functionality in here which brings up the running instance when tried to launch again.

I tried calling ShowWindowAsync() if application is already running,

```
ShowWindowAsync(hWnd, 9);
```

But this fails to bring up the application when minimized to tray.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: @Immanuel - EKS's answer should be acepted. His first link is a great way to do this, much better than checking for process name.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicated of: [What is the correct way to create a single-instance application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-application)

That points to: http://sanity-free.org/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html